# Modifying the insertion type of overlay markers after creation

Tags: overlays

On creation of an overlay it's possible to specify the "insertion type" / advance behavior of the beginning and end markers:

> (make-overlay BEG END &optional BUFFER FRONT-ADVANCE REAR-ADVANCE)

It's possible to change the insertion behavior for markers directly:

> (set-marker-insertion-type MARKER TYPE)
>
> Set the insertion-type of MARKER to TYPE.
>   If TYPE is t, it means the marker advances when you insert text at it.
>   If TYPE is nil, it means the marker stays behind when you insert text at it.

From [Managing Overlays](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Managing-Overlays.html#Managing-Overlays):

> "Do not try modifying the markers in the overlay by hand, as that fails to update other vital data structures and can cause some overlays to be lost."

I get that markers are not easily accessible for the purposes of encapsulation, but I really want to temporarily change the insertion behavior temporarily! :-)  I suppose that I can destructively re-create the overlay twice, but that involves copying properties and any costs associated with underlying overlay data structures.

**Q:** How can I efficiently modify overlay marker insertion types?

If I were to circumvent the intended information-hiding and obtained a reference to individual markers, would modifying the insertion type temporarily (and inserting text) violate an essential invariant for overlay data structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be safe to let the user change the insertion type of the start/end position of an overlay.  It just hasn't been needed until now.  I guess those people who have needed such a thing haven't been vocal enough, or manually adjusting the overlay position (rather than its insertion type) was easy enough.

[ BTW: the fact that overlays use markers is an internal implementation detail.  It will hopefully change in the future.  ]